# How do I parse code coverage value from a cov.xml file in bash?

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have a cov.xml file whose content would be somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<coverage branch-rate="0.802" branches-covered="81" branches-valid="101" complexity="0" line-rate="0.9668" lines-covered="320" lines-valid="331" timestamp="1606253875591" version="5.3">
```

I want to get the value of line-rate from this using a bash command into a variable. What would be the command for that?

Comment: Consider using an XPath expression with an XML specific command line tool, such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). For example: `my_var=$(xml sel -T -t -c "string(/coverage/@line-rate)" cov.xml)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
(venv) [ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ cat cov.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<coverage branch-rate="0.802" branches-covered="81" branches-valid="101" complexity="0" line-rate="0.9668" lines-covered="320" lines-valid="331" timestamp="1606253875591" version="5.3">

(venv) [ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ egrep -o 'line-rate="[^"]+"' cov.xml 
line-rate="0.9668"

(venv) [ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ my_var=$(egrep -o 'line-rate="[^"]+"' cov.xml | cut -d\" -f2)

(venv) [ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ echo $my_var
0.9668
```